# Flutter Firebase How To Merge Streams List and Display on StreamBuilder with Single a Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder, flutter-streambuilder

I have a combine list of streams like that;

```
var Ref1 = _firestore
      .collectionGroup("Posts")
      .where('postID', whereIn: List1)
      .snapshots();
  var Ref2 = _firestore
      .collectionGroup("Posts")
      .where('postID', whereIn: List2)
      .snapshots();
  var Ref3 = _firestore
      .collectionGroup("Posts")
      .where('postID', whereIn: List3)
      .snapshots();
  
  List<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> combineList = [Ref1, Ref2, Ref3];
```

And with this method I merge the Streams from the `combineList`;

```
var totalRef = StreamGroup.merge(combineList);
```

Then I use `totalRef` inside `StreamBuilder`.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: totalRef,
                      builder:
                          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot asyncsnapshot) {
                        if (asyncsnapshot.hasError) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text("Error"),
                          );
                        } else {
                          if (asyncsnapshot.hasData) {
                            List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocumentSnapshot =
                                asyncsnapshot.data.docs;
                            return ListView.builder(
                              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: listOfDocumentSnapshot.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 12.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Stack(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                              child: ClipRRect(
                                                borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(24),
                                                child: GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () => navigateToDetail(
                                                      listOfDocumentSnapshot[
                                                      index]),
                                                  child: Image(
                                                    height: 320,
                                                    width: 320,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                                        listOfDocumentSnapshot[
                                                        index]["photo"]),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          }
                           else {
                            return Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                color: Colors.orangeAccent[400],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      },
                    ),
```

But I run into a problem here. When I use totalRef in StreamBuilder,
Normally, all the results of the 3 merged streams should display in the StreamBuilder, but I only display the data of the last stream(Ref3) in the StreamBuilder.

After I faced this problem, I learned that I had to define the streams I merged in a list form in the `StreamBuilder` and tried the following;

```
List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot =
                                asyncsnapshot.data.toList();

                            List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocumentSnapshot = [];

                            querySnapshot.forEach((query) {
                              listOfDocumentSnapshot.addAll(query.docs);
                            });
```

But when i tried this I got the following error: `Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method 'toList'.`

I tried a different  method after getting that error;

```
List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot;

for (int i = 0; i < combineList.length; i++) {
  querySnapshot.add(asyncsnapshot.data[i]);
 }
                            
 List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocumentSnapshot = [];

 querySnapshot.forEach((query) {
  listOfDocumentSnapshot.addAll(query.docs);
 });
```

I faced a similar problem in this one as well: `Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.`

There is a problem, but I don't understand what the problem is, how can I display all the streams of data.

Comment: use [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html)

Comment: Instead of StreamGroup.merge()? and I keep everything else the same?

Comment: you need to provide `combiner` - a parameter `R combiner(
List<T> values
)` passed to the constructor: see examples in the documentation

Comment: Is there a example for my code so that I can understand it more easily?

Comment: tried to run 3 examples provided? if so, what is unclear?

Comment: This method allows displaying of newly added streams to the list. CombineLatestStream<QuerySnapshot, List<QuerySnapshot>> mergedQuerySnapshot = CombineLatestStream.list(combineList); I did a similar sync like in the example there and wanted to call it in the streambuilder's stream. But i got an error like; The argument type 'CombineLatestStream<QuerySnapshot<Object>, List<QuerySnapshot<Object>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object>>'

Comment: because you did not use a `combiner` - the default `combiner` just return a `List`, the docs say: *"Constructs a CombineLatestStream using a default combiner, which simply yields a List of all latest events emitted by the provided Iterable of Stream."*  - your combiner should merge all the 3 snapshots - for example you can use [combine3](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream/combine3.html) helper method

Comment: The streams in my combine list are variable, so the user can combine all 3 streams, they can combine 2  streams or combine 10 streams, as you said, if I specifically use combine3 or combine9, I would be limited to the number of combines.

Comment: In the CombineLatestStream class, if there is a method to directly combine the streams in my combineList, regardless of the number of streams, I can only use it.

Comment: My problem is that whereIN query can only query 10 values, so I have to query the streams by separating them and then merge them.

Comment: So I need to combine the separate streams somehow and show them in the streambuilder.

Comment: If you use CombineLatest Stream before as dynamic variables, can you write the use appropriate to my example from the answer section, ı cannot understand the use in the link you send me.

Comment: Are you sure my problem is solved with CombineLatest Stream because from what i searched on internet they merge streams with Stream Group.merge or Rx.merge method.

Comment: yes, I am ssure

Comment: So, can you write directly in the answer section how it is done as a code, I wonder I paste it directly into my code and try it, I am new in Flutter and I cannot integrate the method in the link you gave into my code.

Comment: i cannot run it as i have no firestore installed, to be sure check `final stream1 = Stream.value([0, 5, 7]).asBroadcastStream();
final stream2 = Stream.value([2, 4]).asBroadcastStream();

Rx.combineLatest([stream1, stream2], (list) => (list as Iterable<Iterable>).flattened
).listen((v) => print('combineLatest $v'));

Rx.merge([stream1, stream2]).listen((v) => print('merge $v'));` - here `stream1` yields value `[0, 5, 7]` and `stream2` yields `[2, 4]` - the output of combine latest are full 5 values while merge gives two arrays

Comment: I tried what you said. In the example with CombineLatestStream, I output 0.5,7,2,4 in order. If I merge the streams I have with this method, how can I call these merged Streams in the stream builder?
I do something like this;
totalRef = Rx.combineLatest(
        combineList, (list) => (list as Iterable<Iterable>).flattened); I tried to call it inside the stream but got the following error: type 'CombineLatestStream<QuerySnapshot<Object>, Iterable<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?

Comment: do not use `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` - instead use `StreamBuilder<List<Post>>` where `Post` is your custom model class and return `List<Post>` from the `combiner` (and not `(list as Iterable<Iterable>).flattened`)

Comment: When you say List<Post>, is the first of all the post the name of my class?

Comment: I didn't understand what the "Post" is

Comment: Now I got such an error, I keep getting an error, I don't think it will solve. The return type 'Type' isn't a 'QuerySnapshot<Object>', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: It's telling me to upgrade SDK, but when I upgrade, there is no solution.

Comment: It's really surprising that someone has never encountered such a thing before. I'm trying to merge the streams with variable stream numbers and show them in the stream builder, it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Hi @Rkdio, any progress?

Comment: I solved my problem and I uploaded the answer, if anyone is curious, you can take a look.

Comment: I solved my problem, you can check it from this link; [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407597/flutter-firebase-merge-streams-list-with-combinelateststream-and-display-on-stre/70433919#70433919](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407597/flutter-firebase-merge-streams-list-with-combinelateststream-and-display-on-stre)